# Group By Count - Iteration Count LINQ Query

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a table like below,

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | Sample1 |
| A | Sample2 |
| A | Sample3 |
| B | Sample3 |
| B | Sample1 |
| C | Sample2 |
| C | Sample3 |
| D | Sample1 |

If I group the table by Name to get the count,

```
Select Name, Count(*) as count from table group by Name;
```

I will get the following result,

| Name | count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 1 |

I need to get the number of repetitions of each count. Means desired outcome below,

| count | numberOfTimes |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

I know the sql query would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS count,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COUNT(*)) AS numberOfTimes FROM tablename GROUP BY Name;
```

But I am not sure how to write this in LINQ

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
var nameGroups = table.GroupBy(x => x.Name);
var resultCountList = nameGroups
    .Select(g => (
        count: g.Count(), 
        numberOfTimes: nameGroups.Count(ng => g.Count() == ng.Count())))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tnW9P5

The `nameGroups` is just a db-query, so the second query is still using the database until `ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a double grouping gives the intended result.

```
var allCombinedVersion = table
    .GroupBy(e => e.Name)
    .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .GroupBy(e => e.Count)
    .Select(g => new { GroupedCount = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
```

You can test it from [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KdrFfw).
Explained version,

```
var table = new List<Table>
{
    new() { Name = "A", Value = "Sample1" },
    new() { Name = "A", Value = "Sample2" },
    new() { Name = "A", Value = "Sample3" },
    new() { Name = "B", Value = "Sample3" },
    new() { Name = "B", Value = "Sample1" },
    new() { Name = "C", Value = "Sample2" },
    new() { Name = "C", Value = "Sample3" },
    new() { Name = "D", Value = "Sample1" }
};

var groupNames = table.GroupBy(e => e.Name)
    .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();

foreach (var line in groupNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{line.Name} {line.Count}");
}

var groupCounts = groupNames.GroupBy(e => e.Count)
    .Select(g => new { GroupedCount = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();

foreach (var line in groupCounts)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{line.GroupedCount} {line.Count}");
}

internal class Table
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```